# Flooring to nearest multiple of 0.2 in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, rounding, rounding-error

How can I floor a number to the nearest multiple of 0.2 in numpy?

For example, I have this:

```
0.2 * np.floor(xi / 0.2)
```

It works most of the time e.g.

```
>>> xi = 9.4
>>> 0.2 * np.floor(xi / 0.2)
9.4
```

However, it fails for some numbers, such as 9.6

```
>>> xi = 9.6
>>> 0.2 * np.floor(xi / 0.2)
9.4
```

I would expect the previous calculation to return 9.4.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because float format - note that `9.6/0.2` returns `47.9999999...`.

Some rounding here and there will do the trick:

```py
round(0.2*np.floor(round(xi / 0.2,2)),1)
```

Inner rounding is 2 decimal places, to make sure you won't loose the precision, and still will have something to floor.
Outer round is - so you will have proper rounding to `0.2` (and not e.g. `9.6000...1`)

Comment: Hmm. This only works if you're happy for things like `0.399` or `0.599` to be rounded *up* to `0.4` or `0.6` (respectively).

Comment: I mean *some* loss of precision is inevitable. Make the inner rounding to 4 places, and you will capture your cases, but then e.g. ```0.599999``` and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html)

```
0.2 * np.round(xi / 0.2)
```

output:

```
9.600000000000001
```

The little bit extra is due to floating point math.